# Runing a lot of gas

Tags: dodge, fuel-consumption, durango

I have a 2006 Dodge Durango 175,000 miles I had a fuel pump put in Feb of this year, but now I am burning a lot of gas. I have to fill up my truck every four days now. Before I could ride on a full tank of gas for a week and a half. My mechanic put it on the computer and it found nothing wrong. He suggest I get a complete fuel injection cleaning kit. I did but I am still burning a lot of gas. Does anybody know what is happening? Can you tell me what the problem could be?

Comment: Sounds like either leaky injectors or perhaps a fuel leak somewhere. Who installed the new pump? A factory dealer or not a very smart home mechanic (who wired new pump to always 12v hot)?  Fuel pumps (circa 2006) use pulse width modulated signals (PWM) to moderate pressure.

Comment: There is the possibility that someone is stealing your gas overnight... :)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When was the last time the pre-cat O2 sensors were changed? Are you using fuel with more ethanol than you should be (greater than 10%)?

Comment: Do you live in a cold climate where you may be letting your vehicle warm up longer than when it is warm? Many people see a drop in economy during winter months.

Comment: if you are concerned about mileage the very first thing to do is actually carefully document your mileage.  Fill tank completely, write down odometer.  Fill again, do the math.. repeat for at least 2-3 fill ups.